# arithmetic operation in text file

Tags: scripts

I have a data file as follows;

```
569158.650000 8.859e-02
579175.970000 8.659e-02
599177.990000 8.659e-02
```

I need to extract the first-row value from the first column. Then I need to divide the first column by 3600. Finally, I need to paste results as the first column in a new data file as follows;

```
0 8.859e-02
2.78 8.659e-02
8.33 8.659e-02
```

How can I do the above computation using codes?

Comment: how does 569158.650000 / 3600 equal 0? You'll want to research the [tag:awk] language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an `awk` oneliner to solve the problem:

```bsh
awk '{printf "%.2f %s\n", $1/3600, $2}'
```

For every line, this simply divides the first field by 3600 (`$1/3600`) and prints it as a float with two decimals (`%.2f`) followed by space, the second field (`$2`) as a string (`%s`) and finally newline. If you want to round to e.g. six decimal places instead, just change `%.2f` to `%.6f`.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ cat <data
569158.650000 8.859e-02
579175.970000 8.659e-02
599177.990000 8.659e-02
$ awk '{printf "%.2f %s\n", $1/3600, $2}' <data >new_data
$ cat <new_data 
158.10 8.859e-02
160.88 8.659e-02
166.44 8.659e-02
$ awk '{printf "%.6f %s\n", $1/3600, $2}' <data
158.099625 8.859e-02
160.882214 8.659e-02
166.438331 8.659e-02
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
div=3600 #Divisor
scale=2  #Scale for output. Number of digits after decimal point.
while read -r line #Read file into variable line, line by line.
do
    firstnum=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 1) #Pick the first number field
    secondnum=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 2) #Pick the second number field
    firstnum=$(echo "scale=${scale}; ${firstnum}/${div}" | bc -l) #Divide by $div with $scale places after decimal point.
    echo "${firstnum} ${secondnum}" >> output #Output first and second column, seperated by space,to file named output.
done < input #input is name of input file.
```

This script reads from a file named `input` in the format you said, and outputs to a file named `output`.

First it cuts the line into two fields, and then divides first field by 3600 with two decimals printed, and then prints the new number and the second number from the line into a file named output.

It does no error checking. If an error is encountered, YMMV.

Comment: +1 – a safer way is to use `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do`, this allows for the last line to not end in a newline (which else is just silently ignored).